# Anti Aliased ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am currently lazy loading a set of images to my application in android. When I finish loading them,i want to apply a mask(so I can have round corners on them).How can I achieve this effect?(i am not using xml shapes for the round corners, since I want the corners anti-aliased).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are several questions. Please check these out:
• [How to make an ImageView with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners)
• [Creating ImageView with round corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464347/creating-imageview-with-round-corners)
• https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/4j7SLzAGhMk

**Articles on creating custom views** 
• http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html
• http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Comment: The thing is i need it set to an imageview, not to a bitmap

Comment: Either way it doesn't make much difference. You can create a RoundedImageView, and use the same code inside the onDraw() method. If your are using drawables (These are usually of the BitmapDrawable type if you load from image files) call the getBitmap() method to obtain a Bitmap.

Comment: could you give me an example please? i am not understanding very well what you mean

Comment: I think I understand now. But I am lazy loading the images,so when the ondraw is called the drawable is always null

Comment: Doesn't matter, just set the Image once it is available.

Comment: 10-19 14:35:23.569: E/AndroidRuntime(6696): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 14:35:23.569: E/AndroidRuntime(6696): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.UrlImageViewHelper$ZombieDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
10-19 14:35:23.569: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):  at com.koushikdutta.test.widget.RoundSexta.onDraw(RoundSexta.java:39)

i always get this error